# SkiaSharp's PaintSurface not called

Tags: c#, xamarin, skiasharp

Before to start the question, I would like to inform that I am completely newbie to Xamarin...

I would like to understand what I need implement/add/edit in my solution in my project in order to get

`private void canvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)`

being called by:

```
public ColorDemo()
{
    // some code suppressed here, but not related to the question

    SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();

    canvasView.PaintSurface += canvasView_PaintSurface;
    canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
}
```

The solution (Visual Studio 2022) runs ok in my smartphone and/or emulator but the event handler is never called. I tried many things, but no success. I would like to understand the reason why the event handler is never called.

Comment: **1)** [InvalidateSurface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.views.forms.skcanvasview.invalidatesurface) says "This needs to be called from the main thread.". Wrap it in `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.  **2)** If still doesn't draw, maybe it needs to be a child of the currently visible page, for a repaint to happen. Not sure.

Comment: I have seen the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73920745/skiasharp-skglcontol-paintsurface-not-called-might-be-a-problem-with-build-conf#73920745) in a .NET poject, the problem is likely not related to Xamarin. I also found a warning about build target. Do not use `Any CPU`. Up to now, no idea what is causing this problem.